# How do you transfer contacts from iPhone to Android phone through Bluetooth?

Tags: contacts, sync, bluetooth, ios

Is it possible to transfer contacts from iPhone to Android through Bluetooth?
I don't know there is any technical issue to transfer contacts between iPhone and Android by the Bluetooth.
If anybody knows the reason why it's failed, please let me know.
If it's possible, and I did wrong it, please correct me how to Sync contacts through the Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article about my question.
It's not possible because iPhone doesn't support the function to transfer contacts to another device by Bluetooth.(iPhone has never been able to do that)
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3032996